# DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE after new GPU install - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu

My GPU died on me last week and I have since gotten a new one. RX 480 8GB.

I was getting slow startup times (10-15 min) after I first installed the new GPU. I then wiped my C: drive completely clean (didn't keep my files, they were backed up just in case) and reinstalled windows.

It was running fine, then I recieved the blue screen of death with the DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE code.

I have updated all of my drivers, but still get the DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE blue screen every so often. Once it restarts itself it doesn't happen again until I turn my computer off and back on.

I am not sure what to look for. Every guide I've seen said to update drivers which I have done.

Any help is appreciated. Also, someone posted their "dump file" which contained a lot of useful information is seemed. Where can I find that file, and does windows 10 create these files by default?

Thank you.

[Dropbox Link to Dump File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9r1rboyv80q4ep/MEMORY.DMP?dl=0)

EDIT: After looking through the dump file it looks like the bad driver was USBHUB3.sys I'm going to uninstall it and see if it help. I'll post back when I find out.

EDIT 2: So far so good. I've been on for around 10 min now and it usually crashes by then. Hopefully in the clear

Comment: BSOD means dmp files.  windbg can be used to analyze the dmp file to determine if its software (driver) or a hardware problem.  We cannot help you without this file.  If you don't know where they are created, do some research, asking to look really shoudln't be part of your question

Comment: Well, you surely have some sort of bad driver. If you give a link to the .dmp files, it can be looked at in WinDbg to further pinpoint what driver is causing problems.

Comment: @DrZoo I have added the dump file. in the description

Comment: I just saw your message, but it looks like someone was able to analyze it and find the issue. I'm glad your issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Analyzing the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that the crash is not caused by USBhub3.sys, is is caused by `hcwE5bda.sys` which is the [Hauppauge Siena Video Capture Driver](http://www.carrona.org/drivers/driver.php?id=hcwE5bda.sys)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffbc8de5ac5060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd181d91fb960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffbc8de2f007e0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  MS-7758

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  3.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  V2.13

BIOS_DATE:  03/07/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z77A-G41 (MS-7758)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  3.0

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffbc8de5ac5060

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd181d91fb960

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffbc8de2f007e0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  UsbHub3.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5789998e

MODULE_NAME: UsbHub3

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80a01e20000 UsbHub3

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: dac

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3a,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1B'00000000 (cache) 1B'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
02 nt!PopIrpWatchdog
03 nt!KiRetireDpcList
04 nt!KiIdleLoop


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_hcwE5bda_IMAGE_UsbHub3.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_hcwE5bda_IMAGE_UsbHub3.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_hcwE5bda_IMAGE_UsbHub3.sys

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_hcwe5bda_image_usbhub3.sys


6: kd> !podev ffffbc8de5ac5060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject e3fd6560
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 1 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffbc8de5abc040 DevFlags 00003044  DO_POWER_PAGABLE
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffbc8de5ac51d8:
PowerFlags: 00000011 =>SystemState=1 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
6: kd> !devstack ffffbc8de5abc040
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffbc8de5a74e40  \Driver\ksthunk    ffffbc8de5a74f90  00000068
> ffffbc8de5abc040 *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for hcwE5bda.sys
 \Driver\hcwE5bda   ffffbc8de5abc1b0  
  ffffbc8de5ac5060  \Driver\USBHUB3    ffffbc8de5a71e70  USBPDO-13
!DevNode ffffbc8de5b57be0 :
  DeviceInst is "USB\VID_2040&PID_E502\E502-00-00A93EB0"
  ServiceName is "hcwE5bda"
6: kd> lmvm hcwE5bda
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff809`ff7e0000 fffff809`ff8cc380   hcwE5bda   (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: hcwE5bda.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\hcwE5bda.sys
    Image name: hcwE5bda.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Feb  8 21:20:53 2016 (56B8F8A5)
    CheckSum:         000F53A3
    ImageSize:        000EC380
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

so update/remove this Hauppauge driver to fix the issue.

Comment: interesting. When I do a driverqueue it does not show that as being installed. My hauppage capture was plugged into my USB hub, I now have that unplugged because I thought that was what was causing the issue. I guess it all linked together. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I can use my Hub again!