# Windows 10 password prompt not showing on startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, lock-screen

I recently reinstalled windows because I was having some slow loading times after my GPU failed. I have since gotten a new GPU and had some driver issues, but have since fixed them.

However since I reset my windows 10 installation when I first start up the computer and press a key to bring up the password form, nothing shows up. When I **restart** my computer and try it again, it works perfectly fine.

Not sure what the issue is. I have completely wiped my C: drive (didn't keep any of my files). The screen also makes the animation as if it is bringing up the form, but nothing appears. I have even tried typing in the password without the box and it does not work. I have tried ctrl-alt-del as well while on that screen, but again nothing happens. The only way I get it to work is by **restarting** my computer, then it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: Loading into safe mode did not fix it

Comment: which GPU do you use ad wich driver issues do you had? this looks related to your current issue

Comment: I got the RX 480 8GB. The driver issue was with my hauppauge video capture device.

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://superuser.com/questions/1151990/driver-power-state-failure-after-new-gpu-install-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment1657249_1151990 here is where I had help with my driver issue.

Comment: ok, I remember you now. which AMD driver do you use? try the latest 16.11.5 beta driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-16.11.5-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 okay. I will give that a try once I get back on my desktop and will let you know. Thank you

Comment: @magicandre1981 just installed the driver and gave a try. No luck. Still not showing up until I restart my computer.

Comment: a google search shows that several users sometimes run into the issue: https://www.google.com/search?q="windows+10"+password+box+missing maybe a bug, report it via the feedback hub app

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried doing the windows startup repair, that did not work. I then saw that someone had luck but starting in safe mode then restarting. I tried this, then turned my computer off completely and it seems to have worked...

Comment: ok, post your workaround as answer and not add it to the question

Comment: @magicandre1981 just turned in on again today and the same problem arose...it is not fixed

Comment: submit it in feedback hub app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while, but someone finally figured out the problem on the Microsoft forums.

All I had to do was go to my power settings and turn off "fast startup"

Has worked ever since.

To get there on windows 10:

1. Start
2. Type "power options" and click it
3. Click "choose what power buttons do" on the left side
4. Click "change settings that are currently unavailable"
5. You will see the "fast startup" box checked. Uncheck it
6. That's it!

Hope this helps someone else. Very annoying bug.

Answer (score -1):

I see this is a popular issue that might happen temporarily to some people, especially those who left their PC and screen has gone to sleep but log on screen does not show up. 
A quick fix without restarting Windows 10 is to press Ctrl+Alt+Del which brings back the log on screen or might provide extra options. 
Hope this helps some people.

Comment: And what happens then?

Comment: As stated in the question, the user already tried Ctrl-Alt-Del and nothing happened.