# Lockscreen suddenly requires ctrl+alt+del to show login

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

Every once in a while my lock screen suddenly requires me to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> in order to bring up the password screen. Normally pressing any key will do just fine but nothing seems to work.

This isn't like the regular "Please press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log on" message, the lock screen looks like it always does; A Bing wallpaper and a clock. My media keys (pause, play, next, prev etc.) still work and show Spotify changing songs.

Is there a feature that causes this behavior? A reboot gets rid of it but I'd rather not have it show up at all.

Comment: Have you seen the Related? Maybe it is a Fast Startup problem... ? __Link in Related__ https://superuser.com/questions/1152987/windows-10-password-prompt-not-showing-on-startup?rq=1    Windows 10 password prompt not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen on my work PC. I had already checked both the User Accounts "Secure sign-in" setting and the Local Security Policy setting, neither was the culprit. I had also tried running a `gpupdate /force`, which also did not fix it.

But what did fix it, for me, was after pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del to get the password prompt, I subsequently clicked on **Switch User** down in the bottom left corner of the screen. Then, after logging in with my username and password, I pressed Win-L to return to the lock screen and sure enough, just a mouse click or keyboard key press were enough to show the password prompt again!

Comment: This is it! I was having the exact same issue. It has nothing to do with the logon policy, as the other answer suggests, as this is just the basic Windows logon screen already. It just doesn't respond to any input; you can't even hover over the information icon that's displayed as part of the background screen to tell you more about the picture.

But after switching users once, surely enough it started working again!

Answer (score 1):

This article on the Ctrl-Alt-Del function may be the answer: 
[Microsoft Article on Ctrl-ALt-Del at Logon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-require-ctrl-alt-del)

The policy called:
**Interactive Logon: Do not Require ALt-Ctrl-Delete**

at location:
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

This policy has three possible values: Enabled, Disabled and Not defined. I suggest setting it to **Enabled**. This will prevent windows from requiring the Alt-Ctrl-Del function.

I do suggest checking for any malware that can possibly affect your group policies such as this.

Comment: This is for enabling the standard "press ctrl+alt+del to log on" message. I don't get any message, it's just that ctrl+alt+del is the only combination that gets me the login prompt. Normally I just hit spacebar or any other key for the lock screen to fold up.

Comment: What is “This policy”?   Reading your answer by itself (not looking at the link), I have no idea how to apply it.   Please include in your answer all the information that a user would need. … … … … … … … … … … … Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.   Include the link for reference.

Comment: @MMM I've edited my post for clarity after checking on a Win10 PC. I just suggest setting it to enabled and check if the issue remains. In enabled state, windows should never ask for a Alt-Ctrl-Del even in your situation...?